# Is there a way to find out, whether a thread is blocked?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, blocking

I'm writing a thread pool class in C++ which receives tasks to be executed in parallel. I want all cores to be busy, if possible, but sometimes some threads are idle because they are blocked for a time for synchronization purposes. When this happens I would like to start a new thread, so that there are always approximately as many threads awake as there are cpu cores. For this purpose I need a way to find out whether a certain thread is awake or sleeping (blocked). How can I find this out?

I'd prefer to use the C++11 standard library or boost for portability purposes. But if necessary I would also use WinAPI. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7. But really, I'd like to have a portable way of doing this.

Preferably this thread-pool should be able to master cases like

```
MyThreadPool pool;
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    pool.addTask( &block_until_this_function_has_been_called_a_hundred_times );
pool.join(); // waits until all tasks have been dispatched.
```

where the function `block_until_this_function_has_been_called_a_hundred_times()` blocks until 100 threads have called it. At this time all threads should continue running. One requirement for the thread-pool is that it should not deadlock because of a too low number of threads in the pool.

Comment: You could measure the CPU usage at the time, I suppose. But unless your blockages are really quite long (you could keep stats on "how long do I sleep" if you have a wrapper for your locks) then it will probably take longer to start a new thread than the thread is blocked. I'm not aware of any standard way of doing this.

Comment: What do you mean by blocked?  If some of your threads are idle because they are blocked, how does starting another thread help, will it not also be idle waiting for the same resource as the existing threads? As @MatsPetersson says you can measure the idle times of your threads, but perhaps you need to measure the throughput of your resource to keep your threads as busy as possible.

Comment: Why bother?  Just ensure pool, or whatever, has a sufficient number of extra threads.

Comment: @MartinJames I want to avoid over scheduling. If there are too many threads, then performance will slow down because of thread context switches.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky just try it.  What you are suggesting in your OP is to micro-manage threads by impementing in user code what the OS already does.  The OS is very good at transfering control to another thread when a running thread becomes blocked.  What you are planning will almost certainly be counter-productive.  Context-switch overhead only becomes an issue when there are regularly more READY threads than cores AND those threads use so much L1 cache that cache-flushing becomes expensive.

Comment: You can measure the amount of time your threads are blocked on synchronization using a tool like Intel VTune.  But @dwxw's question remains: if your threads are blocked contending for std::mutexes or Windows critical sections, then _that_ is your problem.  Use finer grain synchronization, (or fix your load balancing if it is that kind of program).  Also: as Martin James points out with 2x or 3x (or even 4x) the threads than cpu cores you will _never_ notice the context switch overhead.  OS schedulers are too good for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It has its own thread pool management and scheduling framework. The basic idea is to push tasks to the `io_service` object using the [`post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html) method, and call [`run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) from as many threads as many CPU cores you have. You should create a [`work`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object while the calculation is running to avoid the threads from exiting if they don't have enough jobs.

The important thing about Asio is never to use any blocking calls. For I/O calls, use the asynchronous calls of Asio's own I/O objects. For synchronization, use [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html) objects instead of mutexes. If you post functions to the io service that is wrapped in a strand, then it ensures that at any time at most one task runs that belongs to a certain strand. If there is a conflict, the task remains in Asio's event queue instead of blocking a working thread.

There is one drawback of using asynchronous programming though. It is much harder to read a code that is scattered into several asynchronous calls than one with a clear control flow. You should be aware of this when designing your program.

Answer (score 3):

Add a facility to your thread pool for a thread to say "I'm blocked" and then "I'm no longer blocked". Before every significant blocking action (see below for what I mean by that) signal "I'm blocked", and then "I'm no longer blocked" afterwards.

What constitutes a "significant blocking action"? Certainly not a simple mutex lock: mutexes should only be held for a short period of time, so blocking on a mutex is not a big deal. I mean things like:

- Waiting for I/O to complete
- Waiting for another pool task to complete
- Waiting for data on a shared queue

and other similar events.

Comment: Thanks for making my answer more complete and structured :)